# showing Custom Toast on the right side of Image view in Recycler View

Tags: android

Picture of showing Custom Toast on the right side of Image view in Recycler View

[image: Picture of showing Custom Toast on the right side of Image view in Recycler View]

I want to show a custom toast on the right side of the image view(as shown in the picture), Toast is visible when the current item of recycler view will be 10(or any number). And Toast also changes its position(on scrolling) with the image view till toast is visible.

This is my code

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)           
    {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerViewLTS.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            adapterLTS.setArrayList(arrayListOfJSON);
            recyclerViewLTS.setAdapter(adapterLTS);                          
    }
```

onBindViewHolder

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderLTS holder, int position) {
    if (position == 10){                                                   
     int x = holder.imgeView.getRight();
     int y = holder.imgeView.getTop() + holder.imgeView.getHeight()/2;
     Toast toast = new Toast(getContext());
     toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
     toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
     toast.setView(viewToast);
     toast.show();                                                          
   }                                                                         
 }
```

The problem is that toast is showing at the top of the activity not right side of the image(img 11) may be because the view is attached to an item before going to visible on the screen.

Comment: You can use toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);

Comment: But toast is showing at the top of the activity bcz view is created before going to visible on the screen show at that time the position is different.

Comment: Any specific reason to use `Toast` ? You can create `TextView` inside `Listview` row and make it visible when 10th row is displayed. That will move with your row as its inside your row.

Comment: Because there is already a text view all around the image view. So, only toast can fulfill my requirement. One more placing text view is not possible.

Comment: This toast keeps refreshing on changing the data and user will get easily noticed.